# Search results don't change URL - Web Scraping with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, url, xpath

I am trying to create a python script to scrape the public county records website. I ultimately want to be able to have a list of owner names and the script run through all the names and pull the most recent deed of trust information (lender name and date filed). For the code below, I just wrote the owner name as a string 'ANCHOR EQUITIES LTD'.

I have used Selenium to automate the entering of owner name into form boxes but when the 'return' button is pressed and my results are shown, the website url does not change. I try to locate the specific text in the table using xpath but the path does not exist when I look for it. I have concluded the path does not exist because it is searching for the xpath on the first page with no results shown. BeautifulSoup4 wouldn't work in this situation because parsing the url would only return a blank search form html

See my code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get('http://deed.co.travis.tx.us/ords/f?p=105:5:0::NO:::#results')

ownerName =  browser.find_element_by_id("P5_GRANTOR_FULLNAME")

ownerName.send_keys('ANCHOR EQUITIES LTD')

docType = browser.find_element_by_id("P5_DOCUMENT_TYPE")
docType.send_keys("deed of trust")

ownerName.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

print(browser.page_source)

#lenderName = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"report_results\"]/tbody[2]/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[25]/td[9]/text()")
    enter code here
```

I have commented out the variable that is giving me trouble.. Please help!!!!

If I am not explaining my problem correctly, please feel free to ask and I will clear up any questions.

Comment: is that line of code *throwing* an error, or just what you think is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you almost have it.

You match the element you are interested in using:

```
lenderNameElement = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"report_results\"]/tbody[2]/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[25]/td[9]")
```

Next you access the text of that element:

```
lenderName = lenderNameElement.text
```

Or in a single step:

```
lenderName = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"report_results\"]/tbody[2]/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[25]/td[9]").text
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

have you used following xpath?

```
//table[contains(@summary,"Search Results")]/tbody/tr
```

I have checked it's work perfect.In that, you have to iterate each tr